# How can I select a set of nodes directly linked to a node using views and wikitools

Tags: views, navigation

I'm a newbie with Drupal so I apologize if my question is not presented appropriately, I'll try to be as specific as possible.

So I am developing an academic wiki using Wikitools (gathering academic information such as papers, economic data, etc.). The two types of content I will mention here are (i) Articles - each article presents an academic paper written by one or several authors; and (ii) Authors - a page presenting a particular author/researcher and providing internal and external links related to the researcher (e.g. his website, videos, etc.).

What I would like to do is to select all the Article pages for which a researcher is categorized as an author and display them in the Author page corresponding to that person.

I tried to do that with Views: I created a view, filtered using 'Content type' (i.e. Articles) and 'Links to' as criteria. The view has been integrated into the Author page and links have been established between Article pages and the Author page using Wikitool link format ([[name|name]]).

However, no article pages get displayed in the Author page. I removed the 'Links to' criterion to see what would happen, and all article pages created get displayed. So the view is working correctly but it seems that the links created using the Wikitool format are not recognized as actual links. It's the only explanation I could think of so far, and I could not find any hint in other forums.

So if you guys have any idea, I would really appreciate some help... I'll stay posted to provide additional details if needed.

Thanks a lot for the awesome work you're all doing. I've just discovered Drupal and I still can't believe how innovative and well-designed the whole project is.

Cheers,
Igor

Answer (score 0):

So I found a very simple solution to my problem: I used a contextual filter (in Views) and a Node Reference. Each Article page is linked to corresponding Author page(s) using a node reference. Then using a Contextual Filter in Views, I was able to select all articles written by a given author and display them in the author's page.

I'll give additional details on how to set up the contextual filter, even though it might seem simple to experienced users, new users like me might find the information useful. To set up the contextual filter for the task I described, I selected: 'Provide default value' ('Content ID from URL'), then 'Override title' (and I entered "Articles mentioning %1" in the blank space), 'Specify validation criteria' ('Content', 'Author pages') and 'Node ID' as filter value format.

I don't know whether it can be helpful to someone else but I would have saved a lot of time if I had found that information earlier... :)